# SSRS report stopped loading (Timing out) where as SQL Query pulls data in 48 secs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which worked well until today. It just doesn't load anymore. After waiting 25-30 mins, it shows error message that it has timed out.
Query runs under 48 secs.
I couldn't load report at my local Visual studio too. Where else should I look to fix the issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does your report have any parameters? If it does.. have a look at parameter sniffing issues that SSRS suffers from.

Comment: Harry is right, it is 'probably' parameter sniffing. To test, try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of your dataset query.

Comment: Thanks both! This morning report started working again! Isn't this dngorous..can't predict when Report will work and when will it stop again!? I'm new to SSRS and clueless what trubleshooting steps I can take in this case!